# I can not update patch SUPEE-7405 v1.1

Tags: magento, patch

With the help of this documentation http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

i tried to patch on my magento site. but it gives me error as follows

```
  [~/public_html/my_proj]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.3_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-46-32.sh
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej

    patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php.rej
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Open the files for which you the error message and the rejected files.
For eg: 
 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php.rej.
In the patch file PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.3_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-46-32.sh they have mentioned what is the changes done to this file. Just check it out.